# Calcular checkbox de distintas tablas

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

[CODIGO HTML](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/384790/189565)

** Hola tengo un error que al seleccionar los checkbox y obtener los valores de la ultima, de diferentes tablas.No suma y resta los valores, trae valores incorrectos**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            $('#tabla-ejecuciones input:checkbox').click(function (e) { // seleccionamos el checkbox de la tabla 1 
                calculateSum(8); // calculamos la suma de columna 8

            });

            $('#tabla-boletas input:checkbox').click(function (e) { // seleccionamos el checkbox de la tabla 2
                calculateSum(9); // calculamos la suma de columna 9

            });   

            function calculateSum(importe) {  // Function Calculate Checkbox  checked

                var total = 0;

                $("tr:has(:checkbox:checked) td:nth-child(" + importe + ")").each(function () { // seleccionamos el tr si esta checkeado y tomamos el valor de la ultima columna        


                    total+= parseFloat($(this).text().replace(",", ".")); // parseamos el total en un TXT y remmplazamos la coma por el punto
                   
                });


                $("#lblTotal").text(total.toFixed(2)); // write total en label         




            }
        });

    </script>
```

**Alguna ayuda, por favor!**
[![https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg]

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/keZVI.jpg

Comment: El HTML incluido en la pregunta, no una imagen de la aplicación ;)

Comment: i.stack.imgur.com/keZVI.jpg

Comment: [Edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/384758/edit) para agregar el código HTML, no una imagen de cómo se ve en el navegador.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el HTML?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que liooooooo.. ordena tu pregunta... fijate los links que te pase... si tenes una nueva pregunta, hacela en una nueva pregunta, no en una respuesta... usa el boton [edit] y agrega toda la informacion necesaria aca. Si es otra pregunta sobre la respuesta, comentala o hace una nueva pregunta y referencia esta.

Answer (score 1):

Modifique un poco tu código, pero hace lo que necesitas.

- Puse tu variable de total como un global, por que lo socializas cada que haces el calculo.
- No recorro toda la tabla, por que tendrías que hacer dos recorridos uno de la tabla de ejecuciones y otro de la tabla de boletas.
- Cuando seleccionas un registro mando el evento al calculo, Obtengo el TR mas cercano y obtengo el td de el numero de columna que se manda como parámetro.
- Hago una validación si el campo fue seleccionado o des seleccionado y sumo o resto al total.

```js
var total = 0;
$(function () {
    $('#tabla-ejecuciones input:checkbox').click(function (e) {
        // seleccionamos el checkbox de la tabla 1 
        calculateSum(e, 8); // calculamos la suma de columna 8
    });

    $('#tabla-boletas input:checkbox').click(function (e) { // seleccionamos el checkbox de la tabla 2
        calculateSum(e, 9); // calculamos la suma de columna 9
    });

    function calculateSum(e, importe) {  // Function Calculate Checkbox  checked
        var value = parseFloat($(e.target).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(' + importe + ')').text());
        //Busca el tr de parent mas cercano y luego obtiene el td de el importe
        total = $(e.target).is(':checked') ? (total + value) : (total - value);// valido si el check se selecciono o se desselecciono
        $("#lblTotal").text(total.toFixed(2)); // write total en label
    }

    $('#btnReset').click(function (e) {
        $('.table input:checkbox').each(function (idx, element) {
            $(element).prop("checked", false);
        });
        total = 0;
        $("#lblTotal").text(total.toFixed(2)); // write total en label
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive " id="divboletas">
        <table class="table  table-striped" id="tabla-ejecuciones">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Seleccione</th>

                    <th data-priority="3">Numero</th>
                    <th data-priority="1">Nominal</th>
                    <th data-priority="3">Bonificacion</th>
                    <th data-priority="3">Interes</th>
                    <th data-priority="6">Total boletas</th>
                    <th data-priority="6">Gasto ejecucion</th>
                    <th data-priority="6">Suma Total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="customCheck6" data-parsley-multiple="groups"
                                data-parsley-mincheck="2">

                        </div>
                    </th>

                    <td>14</td>
                    <td>09/2020</td>
                    <td>854</td>
                    <td>225</td>
                    <td>5.5</td>
                    <td>200</td>
                    <td>2250,25</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="customCheck6" data-parsley-multiple="groups"
                                data-parsley-mincheck="2">

                        </div>
                    </th>

                    <td>14</td>
                    <td>09/2020</td>
                    <td>854</td>
                    <td>225</td>
                    <td>5.5</td>
                    <td>200</td>
                    <td>3560,03</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-row" id="customCheck6" data-parsley-multiple="groups"
                                data-parsley-mincheck="2">
                        </div>
                    </th>

                    <td>14</td>
                    <td>09/2020</td>
                    <td>854</td>
                    <td>225</td>
                    <td>5.5</td>
                    <td>200</td>
                    <td>6031,08</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-row" id="customCheck6" data-parsley-multiple="groups"
                                data-parsley-mincheck="2">
                        </div>
                    </th>

                    <td>14</td>
                    <td>09/2020</td>
                    <td>854</td>
                    <td>225</td>
                    <td>5.5</td>
                    <td>200</td>
                    <td>2501,69</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-row" id="customCheck6" data-parsley-multiple="groups"
                                data-parsley-mincheck="2">
                        </div>
                    </th>
                    <td>14</td>
                    <td>09/2020</td>
                    <td>854</td>
                    <td>225</td>
                    <td>5.5</td>
                    <td>200</td>
                    <td>950,30</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br>
        <br>

        <br>
        <br>



        <table class="table  table-striped" id="tabla-boletas">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Seleccione</th>
                    <th data-priority="2">Año</th>
                    <th data-priority="3">Cuota</th>
                    <th data-priority="1">F.Vencimiento</th>
                    <th data-priority="3">Importe</th>
                    <th data-priority="3">Bonificacion</th>
                    <th data-priority="6">Plan pago</th>
                    <th data-priority="6">Interes</th>
                    <th data-priority="6">Total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="customCheck6" data-parsley-multiple="groups"
                                data-parsley-mincheck="2">

                        </div>
                    </th>
                    <td>2020</td>
                    <td>14</td>
                    <td>09/2020</td>
                    <td>854</td>
                    <td>225</td>
                    <td>5.5</td>
                    <td>200</td>
                    <td>731,25</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="customCheck6" data-parsley-multiple="groups"
                                data-parsley-mincheck="2">

                        </div>
                    </th>
                    <td>2020</td>
                    <td>14</td>
                    <td>09/2020</td>
                    <td>854</td>
                    <td>225</td>
                    <td>5.5</td>
                    <td>200</td>
                    <td>1731,03</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-row" id="customCheck6" data-parsley-multiple="groups"
                                data-parsley-mincheck="2">
                        </div>
                    </th>
                    <td>2020</td>
                    <td>14</td>
                    <td>09/2020</td>
                    <td>854</td>
                    <td>225</td>
                    <td>5.5</td>
                    <td>200</td>
                    <td>431,08</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-row" id="customCheck6" data-parsley-multiple="groups"
                                data-parsley-mincheck="2">
                        </div>
                    </th>
                    <td>2020</td>
                    <td>14</td>
                    <td>09/2020</td>
                    <td>854</td>
                    <td>225</td>
                    <td>5.5</td>
                    <td>200</td>
                    <td>231,69</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-row" id="customCheck6" data-parsley-multiple="groups"
                                data-parsley-mincheck="2">
                        </div>
                    </th>
                    <td>2020</td>
                    <td>14</td>
                    <td>09/2020</td>
                    <td>854</td>
                    <td>225</td>
                    <td>5.5</td>
                    <td>200</td>
                    <td>731</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br>
        <br>



        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="example-number-input" class="pull-right">IMPORTE TOTAL:<span class="badge badge-danger font-18"
                id="lblTotal"> </span></label>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="btnReset">Resetear</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {


        $('#tabla-ejecuciones input:checkbox').click(function (
            e) { // seleccionamos el checkbox de la tabla 1
            calculateSum();
        });

        $('#tabla-boletas input:checkbox').click(function (e) { // seleccionamos el checkbox de la tabla 2
            calculateSum();
        });

        function calculateSum() {
            var total = 0;
            $("tr:has(:checkbox:checked)").each(
                function () { // seleccionamos el tr si esta checkeado y tomamos el valor de la ultima columna
                    if ($(this).parents()[1].id == "tabla-ejecuciones") {
                        console.log($(this).children()[7]);
                        total += parseFloat($(this).children()[7].textContent.replace(",",
                            "."));
                    } else if ($(this).parents()[1].id == "tabla-boletas") {
                        total += parseFloat($(this).children()[8].textContent.replace(",",
                            "."));
                    }

                }
            );

            $("#lblTotal").text(total.toFixed(2)); // write total en label
        }

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="table-responsive "  id="divboletas">




                                        <table class="table  table-striped" id="tabla-ejecuciones">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Seleccione</th>

                                                    <th data-priority="3">Numero</th>
                                                    <th data-priority="1">Nominal</th>
                                                    <th data-priority="3">Bonificacion</th>
                                                    <th data-priority="3">Interes</th>
                                                    <th data-priority="6">Total boletas</th>
                                                    <th data-priority="6">Gasto ejecucion</th>
                                                    <th data-priority="6">Suma Total</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>
                                                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                            <input type="checkbox" id="customCheck6"
                                                                data-parsley-multiple="groups"
                                                                data-parsley-mincheck="2">

                                                        </div>
                                                    </th>

                                                    <td>14</td>
                                                    <td>09/2020</td>
                                                    <td>854</td>
                                                    <td>225</td>
                                                    <td>5.5</td>
                                                    <td>200</td>
                                                    <td>2250,25</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>
                                                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                            <input type="checkbox" id="customCheck6"
                                                                data-parsley-multiple="groups"
                                                                data-parsley-mincheck="2">

                                                        </div>
                                                    </th>

                                                    <td>14</td>
                                                    <td>09/2020</td>
                                                    <td>854</td>
                                                    <td>225</td>
                                                    <td>5.5</td>
                                                    <td>200</td>
                                                    <td>3560,03</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>
                                                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-row"
                                                                id="customCheck6" data-parsley-multiple="groups"
                                                                data-parsley-mincheck="2">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </th>

                                                    <td>14</td>
                                                    <td>09/2020</td>
                                                    <td>854</td>
                                                    <td>225</td>
                                                    <td>5.5</td>
                                                    <td>200</td>
                                                    <td>6031,08</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>
                                                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-row"
                                                                id="customCheck6" data-parsley-multiple="groups"
                                                                data-parsley-mincheck="2">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </th>

                                                    <td>14</td>
                                                    <td>09/2020</td>
                                                    <td>854</td>
                                                    <td>225</td>
                                                    <td>5.5</td>
                                                    <td>200</td>
                                                    <td>2501,69</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>
                                                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-row"
                                                                id="customCheck6" data-parsley-multiple="groups"
                                                                data-parsley-mincheck="2">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </th>
                                                    <td>14</td>
                                                    <td>09/2020</td>
                                                    <td>854</td>
                                                    <td>225</td>
                                                    <td>5.5</td>
                                                    <td>200</td>
                                                    <td>950,30</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                        <br>
                                        <br>
                                       
                                        <br>
                                        <br>



                                        <table class="table  table-striped" id="tabla-boletas">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Seleccione</th>
                                                    <th data-priority="2">Año</th>
                                                    <th data-priority="3">Cuota</th>
                                                    <th data-priority="1">F.Vencimiento</th>
                                                    <th data-priority="3">Importe</th>
                                                    <th data-priority="3">Bonificacion</th>
                                                    <th data-priority="6">Plan pago</th>
                                                    <th data-priority="6">Interes</th>
                                                    <th data-priority="6">Total</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>
                                                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                            <input type="checkbox" id="customCheck6"
                                                                data-parsley-multiple="groups"
                                                                data-parsley-mincheck="2">

                                                        </div>
                                                    </th>
                                                    <td>2020</td>
                                                    <td>14</td>
                                                    <td>09/2020</td>
                                                    <td>854</td>
                                                    <td>225</td>
                                                    <td>5.5</td>
                                                    <td>200</td>
                                                    <td>731,25</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>
                                                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                            <input type="checkbox" id="customCheck6"
                                                                data-parsley-multiple="groups"
                                                                data-parsley-mincheck="2">

                                                        </div>
                                                    </th>
                                                    <td>2020</td>
                                                    <td>14</td>
                                                    <td>09/2020</td>
                                                    <td>854</td>
                                                    <td>225</td>
                                                    <td>5.5</td>
                                                    <td>200</td>
                                                    <td>1731,03</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>
                                                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-row"
                                                                id="customCheck6" data-parsley-multiple="groups"
                                                                data-parsley-mincheck="2">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </th>
                                                    <td>2020</td>
                                                    <td>14</td>
                                                    <td>09/2020</td>
                                                    <td>854</td>
                                                    <td>225</td>
                                                    <td>5.5</td>
                                                    <td>200</td>
                                                    <td>431,08</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>
                                                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-row"
                                                                id="customCheck6" data-parsley-multiple="groups"
                                                                data-parsley-mincheck="2">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </th>
                                                    <td>2020</td>
                                                    <td>14</td>
                                                    <td>09/2020</td>
                                                    <td>854</td>
                                                    <td>225</td>
                                                    <td>5.5</td>
                                                    <td>200</td>
                                                    <td>231,69</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>
                                                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-row"
                                                                id="customCheck6" data-parsley-multiple="groups"
                                                                data-parsley-mincheck="2">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </th>
                                                    <td>2020</td>
                                                    <td>14</td>
                                                    <td>09/2020</td>
                                                    <td>854</td>
                                                    <td>225</td>
                                                    <td>5.5</td>
                                                    <td>200</td>
                                                    <td>731</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                        <br>
                                        <br>



                                        <br>
                                        <br>
                                        <label for="example-number-input" class="pull-right">IMPORTE TOTAL:<span
                                                class="badge badge-danger font-18" id="lblTotal"> </span></label>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: Esto es parte de tu pregunta?

Comment: si , lo que no logro hacer es q realice la suma de los checkbox , boteniendo el ultimo valor de las columnas y sumarlas al seleccionar el check ( en una tabla lo hace perfectamente, pero al seleccionar el checkbox de otra tabla, no realiza correctamente la suma o resta al seleccionar el checkbox) la suma de los ultimos TD funciona solo  cuando seleccionamos los checkbox de una tabla. Si queremos sumar valores de otra tabla , devuelve valores incorrectos a la suma ( Tabla 1 tiene 8 columnas y tabla 2 tiene 9 columnas, la accion es sumar los valores de las ultimas columnas de ambas tablas)

Comment: soy nuevo en stackoverflow